# Select position of CardView in RecyclerView and Change Fragment in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

*** EASY PART ***

At the moment I have set up a CardView inside a RecyclerView.

What i need to do is to change the color of the 2nd cardview to yellow, and the 3rd cardview to red (At the moment they are all green). Also i want the first cardview to remain green.

*** HARD PART ***

What i also need, is to be able to switch to another fragment, whenever i click on one of the CardViews in the RecyclerView. So basically to switch fragments in my RecyclerAdapter.

My RecyclerAdapter Java class is as follows:

Thanks in advance!`

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

Fragment fragment;

private DataTabelFragment dataTabelFragment;

private static String[] title = new String[]{"D42DB2", "B42DC6", "CURRENTLY NOT AVAILABLE"};

private static String[] beskrivelse = new String[]{"Temperatur & Humdity Sensorer", "Light Sensorer", ""};


@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    System.out.println( "DU ER KOMMET SÅ LANGT HABEBEEEEEEEEE" );

    View view = LayoutInflater.from( viewGroup.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.fragment_card_view_tabel, viewGroup, false );

    viewGroup.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    } );

    return new RecyclerViewHolder( view );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int i) {

    recyclerViewHolder.mBeskrivelse.setText( beskrivelse[i] );
    recyclerViewHolder.mTitle.setText( title[i] );

    recyclerViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( "#FFCE54" ) );


    //recyclerViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( "#FFCE54" ) );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return title.length;
}

class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView mBeskrivelse;
    private TextView mTitle;
    private CardView cardView;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super( itemView );

        mBeskrivelse = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.item_beskrivelse );
        mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.item_title );
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.card_view );
        itemView.setOnClickListener( this );

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText( itemView.getContext(), "HEJ DU HAR TRYKKET PÅ KNAP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        //((FragmentActivity) itemView.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.recycler_view, new DataTabelFragment() ).commit();


    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, you can just do the same thing you do with the titles. Add an array similar to this.

```
private static String[] colors = new String[]{"#FFCE54", "#57ad48", "#c93e3c"};
```

Then access it like this.

```
recyclerViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( colors[i] ) );
```

You could also set the onClickListener inside the onBindViewHolder like this.

```
recyclerViewHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.recycler_view, new DataTabelFragment() ).commit();
    }
});
```

Or add it as an onItemTouchListener to your RecyclerView.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
          getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.recycler_view, new DataTabelFragment() ).commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A short clarify :

1. If you want to change only the first 3 `cardview`colors then you can simply check the position and do the job. But I suppose you want this to be a bit more customized, therefore you'll have to `@Override getItemViewtype`method of the adapter, and based on that you can show different views in the `Recyclerview. [Sample](https://gist.github.com/afollestad/c84e259e98a03134dfd5)
2. Now, about the fragment you want to show from each cardview.. I see you are trying to do that from within the adapter. I suggest you do it from activity / fragment [RecyclerView Listener] (https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/) properly implemented. In addition to this, you'll want to use `add()` method instead of `replace` for fragment transaction (this way you will have your list still shown below the added fragment, and you won't have to inflate or start the fragment again.